# Can't submit form in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I noticed that the following form can not be submitted by jquery submit() function. The problem seems to be the id of button, which shouldn't be "submit". Why does it work like this?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

  <form action="" id="Foo" method="POST">  

   <button id="submit" >Bla</button>
  </form>
```

And I called the following line in console:

```
$('#Foo').submit();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

Even though it submits already

but if you had to submit manually using jquery you have to use this :

```
$('#Foo')[0].submit();
```

as the selection by jquery returns an array of objects related to the dom, the first is the dom itself, so you can submit it this way

**Edit**:

if you want to prevent it from submitting use this :

```
$('#submit').onclick(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit 2**:

If you use the tag `<button>` you should always declare the intended `type` attribute. In some browsers the default is "submit" while others have the default value of "button".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I doubt it's not for the problem here. If I change the id of button to something else, it'll just work :(

Comment: You saved our lives :D

Answer (score 1):

please change your submit button:

from:

```
<button id="submit" >Bla</button>
```

into:

```
<input class="submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Bla" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should submit with form Id and not with submit button id.

```
$('#Foo').submit();
```

Even with Id `"submit"` its submitting .

Check fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1342/

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, that's what I did :( If I change id of the button to something other than "submit", this works

Comment: So,please change it.What was the problem ?

Comment: As described in the question now, if there's a button with id="submit" inside the form, I can't submit the form by calling $('#Foo').submit();

Comment: Problem lies some where else.Check the fiddle.

Comment: Hmm, it does work in fiddle, but still not in my computer. Using the latest version of jquery, tested on Chrome and IE10. The problem has been identified by a coworker as well